# insertar multiples tablas sql php

Tags: php, sql

Tengo 4 tablas para insertar datos a la vez pero solo me inserta en la primera y las otras 3 no, me imagino que estoy haciendo algo mal en la parte de ingresar los datos, acá les dejo el php para insertar los datos

```
            $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
        $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
        $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
        $montoPrestamo = $_POST['monto'];
        $cuotas = $_POST['cuotas'];
        $montoCuota = $_POST['montoCuota'];
        $tasaInteres = $_POST['tasaInteres'];
        $fechaPrimerDescuento = $_POST['fechaPrimerDescuento'];
        $cuota = $_POST['cuota'];
        $montoPago = $_POST['montoPago'];
        $fechaPago = $_POST['fechaPago'];
        $observacion = $_POST['observacion'];
        $estado = 0;
        $fechaCuotaEspecial = $_POST['fechaCuotaEspecial'];
        $montoCuotaEspecial = $_POST['montoCuotaEspecial'];
        $fechaPagoEspecial = $_POST['fechaPagoEspecial'];
        $montoPagoEspecial = $_POST['montoPagoEspecial'];



        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO prestamo (cedulaAsociado, descripcion, tipo, fecha, monto, cuotas, montoCuota, tasaInteres, fechaPrimerDescuento, observacion, estado)
                                    VALUES ('$cedulaGET', '$descripcion', '$tipo', '$fecha', '$montoPrestamo', '$cuotas', '$montoCuota', '$tasaInteres', '$fechaPrimerDescuento', '$observacion', '$estado')");

        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO pago (cuota, fecha, monto) VALUES ('$cuota', '$fechaPago', '$montoPago')");

        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO cuotaEspecial (fecha, monto) VALUES ('$fechaCuotaEspecial', '$montoCuotaEspecial')");
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO pagoespecial (fecha, monto) VALUES ('$fechaPagoEspecial', '$montoPagoEspecial')");
```

DB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te sale algun error? posiblemente sea  los tipos de datos que no encajan con los atributos de las tablas en la DB,  posiblemente en un campo declarado como INT estas pasando una variable en formato String o Varchar  por que estoy viendo que todos tus variables(en el php) son  cadenas por que están encerradas entre comillas simples. Seria bueno que puedas mostrar la estructura de tus tablas de tu DB

Comment: Pensé lo mismo pero no, en la primera tabla prestamo me registró bien los números a pesar de que estuvieran en comillas simples. Las otras 3 no registran. De todos modos colocaré una imagen de la base de datos en edición

Comment: tus llaves foraneas las has declarado null por defecto? posiblemente sea eso que no te deja insertar los datos por tu llave foranea revizala

Comment: Si estaba null, no me di ceunta de ese fallo pero las cambié y aún no registran

Comment: me refería a que debe ser: "null" y no:"not null", si es "no null" no de te dejará insertar porque será un campo requerido.

Comment: Eh probado tu código y funciona bien, el otro error posible puede estar en lo que contiene las variables después de ser cargadas por los $_POST[´´], fijate que no este recibiendo un dato null en los $_POST, revísalo con un echo antes de meterlos en el INSERT, para ver si te llegan correctamente.

Comment: Ok, lo intentaré